# ¿Como evitar la inyeccion SQL en este codigo de Php y crear colas MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, seguridad

tengo este código en un sistema que estoy desarrollando, funciona pero yo se que debo meterle seguridad y también dejarlo para que funcione a largo plazo, por lo cual me gustaría saber como evitar que se caiga la base de datos, al varios usuarios ingresar información al mismo tiempo, por ultimo hay algún problema si no divido en clases todo el código?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
include_once 'resource/Database.php';


try {


$sql = "INSERT INTO capturar_pedido (cliente,
orden_de_compra,
producto,
unidad,
cantidad,
fecha_de_embarque,
notas,
etiquetado)
VALUES ('".$_POST["cliente"]."','".$_POST["orden_de_compra"]."','".$_POST["producto"]."','".$_POST["unidad"]."','".$_POST["cantidad"]."','".$_POST["fecha_de_embarque"]."','".$_POST["notas"]."','".$_POST["etiquetado"]."')";


if ($db->query($sql)) {
     echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
} 
else{
     echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
}

    $db = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}

?>

<?php
include_once 'resource/Database.php';

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM capturar_pedido");
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sql->execute();


if($sql->rowCount() != 0) {

?>
<table class="table table-condensed">
   <tr>
      <td>cliente</td>
      <td>Orden de compra</td>
      <td>Producto</td>
             <td>Unidad</td>
             <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>Fecha de embarque</td>
      <td>Notas</td>
      <td>Etiquetado</td>


   </tr>
 <?php     
 while($row=$sql->fetch()) 
 {
      echo "<tr>".
           "<td>".$row["cliente"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["orden_de_compra"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["producto"]."</td>".
                     "<td>".$row["unidad"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["cantidad"]."</td>".
                     "<td>".$row["fecha_de_embarque"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["notas"]."</td>".
           "<td>".$row["etiquetado"]."</td>".


           "</tr>";
 }

}
else
{
     echo "don't exist records for list on the table";
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: A como veo no utilizas tecnología ajax, yo te recomendaría que lo utilizaras ya que es lo que se está usando ahora. Puedes investigar en internet como manejar tokens para la seguridad y que no haya inyeccion de datos.

Comment: Son 3 preguntas en 1. Será difícil que obtengas una respuesta satisfactoria. **1** Sí, es urgente que le des más seguridad al código, usando consultas preparadas [aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d6z8-n7s1); **2** ¿La base de datos se cae? ¿Cuál es el motivo de que se caiga? **3** ¿Dividir en clases? Si no divides el código en clases no hay problema, pero hoy en día se recomienda representar cada entidad de tu aplicación con una clase. Así, tendrás la clase `Conexion`, la clase `Persona` la clase `Estudiante` que extiende de `Persona`, quizá una clase `Utilidades`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar inyección de SQL usa prepared statements para acceder a la base de datos.
Cuando haces esto en el string del query usas signos de interrogación para marcar donde después irán los datos.
Los datos en sí se asocian con el query en una segunda instancia que le permite a la base de datos saber positivamente que aunque le llegue sql inyectado, igual se trata de datos.